# how does the javascript function get the parameter values?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

When I learn how to custom "lookup" popup window, following the blog(http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/), I have a question that how does the function openLookup get the parameter values without calling this function (I know a little about Javascript )?

visualforce code

```
<apex:page controller="MyCustomLookupController" id="Page" tabstyle="Contact">

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
    var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
    var originalwidth = width;
    var originalmodified = modified;
    var originalsearchParam = searchParam;

    var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
    if (modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;

    var isCustomLookup = false;

    // Following "001" is the lookup type for Account object so change this as per your standard or custom object
    if(lookupType == "001"){

      var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
      var txtId = '';
      if(urlArr.length > 2) {
        urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
        txtId = urlArr[1];
      }

      // Following is the url of Custom Lookup page. You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = "/apex/CustomAccountLookup?txt=" + txtId;

      // Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm". You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" + escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
      if (modified == '1') {
        baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
      }

      // Following is the ID of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
      if(txtId.indexOf('Account') > -1 ){
        isCustomLookup = true;
      }
    }


    if(isCustomLookup == true){
      openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    }
    else {
      if (modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
      openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+originalwidth+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    } 
  }
</script>

<apex:sectionHeader title="Demo"  subtitle="Custom Lookup" />

  <apex:form id="myForm">  
    <apex:PageBlock id="PageBlock">        
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Custom Lookup">
        <apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!contact.AccountId}"  />
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:PageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Wish for your help!

Comment: I think its a salesforce standard JavaScript function defined, and on click of glass icon, it automatically passes them as parameter. They might have written a click handler which does it. So, when you define openLookup function, it overrides the actual function defined by Salesforce.

Comment: Basically, this code overrides the standard openLookup function found in the JS library included on every page load. The four parameters are baked into the way the magnifying glass icon is rendered, so no nothing needs to be provided at all when you use apex:inputField. If you were also writing your own custom HTML code, you'd have to provide an appropriate onClick method to call the function.